# How to access the application in azure managed kubernetes service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, swaggerhub

I am very new in a kubernetes world and learning things. I have some situation where i have installed a application(SwaggerHub) in a azure kubernetes service. I follow the installation instructions from swaggerHub [documentation](https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/docs/enterprise/latest/install/cluster/online.html). Everything work smoothly and now i have a wondering that how to access the UI via IP address. As per documentation it is required to setup a DNS for this but I guess it is just for production use and for a testing purpose i can access the main UI through IP address.

[image]

I tried to access the application from the external IP address which i can see in LoadBalancer service but it is not working. Any idea how i can access the service via IP address ?

Comment: I suggest also asking [SwaggerHub support](https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/message/).

Comment: Just to get a correct understanding. You have a Service of Type LoadBalancer for the UI Service of Swagger correct? Or did you have to manually add that Service.

If the LoadBalancer get's a valid IP from your Cloud Provider, and nothing blocks access to it from Azure side, it should work.

Comment: No, I have not added this manually. This appear after an installation of swaggerHub. I am confuse that why this LB is a part of Kube-system and not in SwaggerHub Pods .

Comment: Can you please check the NSG rules that you have added or not, DenyAllInbound will block the traffic.
Could you please create appropriate NSG rules to allow inbound rules from Internet.
If it does not work, kindly provide some additional information around the configuration of NSGs